# Horizontal lists in a Wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, list, alignment

I have to build a Wordpress website for a project. However, I have an issue with my categorie lists : they are all displayed vertically, and I can't make them display horizontally :

Here is the website : http://www.videotechlab.com/?videoscategory=camera

The main issue is I don't know what part of the CSS I have to edit. I tried multiple times with no result.

Any help would be appreciated.

Best regards.

GL

Comment: Remove the `clearfix` class from each `<li>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the class "clearfix" from your `<li>` tags.

Clearfix is designed to stop elements with CSS `float: left|right` from mucking up the rest of the page.

Comment: Aidan is correct, the `clearfix` class is what's causing your li's to be cleared and not floated. Clearfix should be used on the parent `ul.categories_list`.

Comment: Hello Aidan, thank you for your answer. The thing is I don't have access to the HTML, only the CSS (or maybe there is something I don't get, I'm kinda new to this)

Comment: @Aidan You're answer is not exactly correct, clearfix is a hack to allow the parent of any floated content to obtain the correct dimensions based on it's floated child elements. "mucking up" is not the best defanition.

Comment: @hitautodestruct Many thanks for clarifying that. @ user2715157 I'd suggest asking for access to the HTML? It's not ideal to come up with a CSS hack to stop clearfix...

Comment: I have FTP access but I only see php files, not HTML, something I can do with PHP?

Comment: @user2715157 Wordpress has a number PHP functions for things like listing categories, taxonomies and so on that you can use in themes/plugins - check out the documentation for [wp_list_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories). Really, this is a separate question - of which there will be many answers on Google i'd imagine.

Comment: I simply deleted the class="clearfix" in the php tag <li> and it worked. Aidan was right, thank you very much guys, you rock :) !